# Silverlight 4: "Invalid XAML" using Converter in DataTemplate

Tags: silverlight, visual-studio-2010, xaml, silverlight-4.0, designer

maybe you could help me understand why I get an unhandled exception "Invalid XAML" in Visual Studio 2010 designer when trying to do the following on a `Page`.

I have a `Converter` named `DateTimeConverter` that converts a date into a German date string. The converter works fine. I've included the namespace and added the following to the page's resources:

```
<navigation:Page.Resources>
    <myClasses:DateTimeConverter x:Key="dateTime" />
</navigation:Page.Resources>
```

Now I have a list box that I want to bind to a list of objects. I do the binding in code, but I would like to define the data template. Thus I've added the following to my layout:

```
<ListBox x:Name="lbConversation" BorderBrush="#00000000">
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Border BorderThickness="0" Padding="4">
                <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Message, Mode=OneWay}" />
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding TimeStamp, Mode=OneWay, Converter={StaticResource dateTime}}" />
                </StackPanel>
            </Border>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

And this works fine when I run. However, in the code section, the code for the data template is undercurled and the designer says "Invalid XAML". When I remove the `Converter=...` part, this error is gone.

Is this a designer bug? What can I do?

**EDIT**
By the way: The exact same code does not throw the error within a WPF project!

Comment: Do you made a build after defining the converter in xaml and applying it in the DataTemplate?

Comment: As I said in my question: everything's fine when I run the application - which implies that I built it :-) Also: I've accepted an answer before I read your comment - that solves it.

Comment: For anyone coming in from Google: I also found I had this issue when I was pulling a namespace into my XAML file that no longer existed.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just adding to this question as I found a solution.

The solution to my case was here: http://forums.silverlight.net/post/618518.aspx

Apparently you must not have a space character in your project name or assembly name. D'oh!

Hope it helps.

Comment: I totally forgot about this question. When I got errors in "normal" WPF too, I realized that spaces in assembly names cause this problem.

Comment: I don't have a space in neither of my assemblies and I encounter this issue, is there any way to debug the designer to find the real problem?

Comment: Be careful to change both project name (rename it) AND assembly name (right click on project / properties / assembly name).

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, can't replicate this at all, do you have some design-time data that may be the cause of the weird error?

Also, since you said that you're using the converter to output german dates... wouldn't it be easier to let the framework do this kind of things, as it probably does them a lot better? Set the entire application thread's CultureInfo to german and all formatting will be done with that culture's settings; of course it's still possible you only want some controls internationalized...

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply. Of course I could handle the date formatting by framework. But I have other converters too, and the problem uccurs also for those converters.

Answer (score 1):

I can't see anything wrong with your Xaml however I wonder if this is a result of the language setting used when the Xaml is parsed.  By default Xaml is parsed using the `InvariantCulture` however it would appear that the designer in visual studio parses the Xaml using the current culture.  Hence at times you can get unexpected differences in behaviour at design time than you do at runtime.

In fact if you do this in the constructor of your `UserControl` before calling `InitializeComponent`:-

```
 this.Language = XmlLanguage.GetLanguage(Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.Name);
```

You might not need your converter at all.

Answer (score 0):

I came across "Invalid XAML" error when I had my converter marked internal. Change the modifier to public and everything is as expected.

Hope this help.