# C# windows phone xaml showing invalid xaml error

Tags: c#, wpf, windows, xaml

Hello I am developing a windows phone app and below some code its showing a blue line which reads "invalid xaml" but there's no problem in compilation or run. I am converting image to byte to store it in the isostorage and while binding I'm converting it back.
My code is:

```
<StackPanel Height="auto" Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="0,0,0,0" Grid.RowSpan="2">
        <StackPanel Width="80" Orientation="Horizontal" Height="auto" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Left">
            <Ellipse Margin="0" Height="70" Width="70" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Stroke="{x:Null}">
                <Ellipse.Fill>
                        <ImageBrush Stretch="Fill" ImageSource="{Binding imageBytes, Converter={StaticResource BytesToImageConverter}}"/>
                </Ellipse.Fill>
            </Ellipse>
        </StackPanel>
        <StackPanel Height="auto" Width="380" HorizontalAlignment="Left">
            <TextBlock FontWeight="Bold"  Text="{Binding FirstName}" FontFamily="Segoe WP Semibold" FontSize="30" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="5,0,0,0" HorizontalAlignment="Left" />
            <StackPanel>
                    <ListBox SelectionChanged="Contactlist2_SelectionChanged_1" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" x:Name="Contactlist2" ItemsSource="{Binding PhoneNumbers}" Margin="10,0,0,0">
                        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <StackPanel Height="auto" Margin="5,0,0,0">
                    <TextBlock FontSize="25" Text="{Binding}" FontFamily="Segoe WP"  Margin="10,0,0,0" Width="320" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="40" />
                    <TextBlock FontSize="20" Text="mobile" Width="302"/>
                </StackPanel>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>

    </ListBox>
        </StackPanel>
    </StackPanel>
    </StackPanel>
```

If I remove

```
ImageSource="{Binding imageBytes, Converter={StaticResource BytesToImageConverter}}"
```

My convertor code is:

```
 public class BytesToImageConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (value != null && value is byte[])
        {
            byte[] bytes = value as byte[];
            MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream(bytes);
            BitmapImage image = new BitmapImage();
            image.DecodePixelType = DecodePixelType.Logical;
            image.CreateOptions = BitmapCreateOptions.BackgroundCreation;
            image.CreateOptions = BitmapCreateOptions.DelayCreation;
            var bitmapImage = PictureDecoder.DecodeJpeg(stream, 480, 856);
            if (bitmapImage.PixelHeight > bitmapImage.PixelWidth)
            {
                image.DecodePixelWidth = 56;
                image.DecodePixelHeight = 100;
            }
            else
            {
                image.DecodePixelWidth = 100;
                image.DecodePixelHeight = 56;
            }
            image.SetSource(stream);
            return image;
        }

        return null;

    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

From imagebrush error goes away. What's wrong? Thank you.

Comment: the designer often has these kind of errors, you can safely ignore them. You can tell by closing the code window with the error, then the error indication should go away too.

Comment: Check your converter

Comment: Check your project name first, hope it does not contain any spaces !!

Comment: @adityaswami89 yeah it does contain spaces but in the namespace it shows underscores in between.

Comment: may be you want to keep it simple without any spaces. It should work !!

Comment: @adityaswami89 I think problem is with my Imagesource, because if I remove it, error vanishes.

Comment: Can you please try changing the assembly name and project name without any spaces,from the properties window of the project ?
This way we can remove 1 possible solution out . Since also in many  places this seems to be the problem :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3759441/silverlight-4-invalid-xaml-using-converter-in-datatemplate

Comment: @adityaswami89 It worked like a charm :) but still I'm curious what was the error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is due to spaces in the namespace or in the project name. There has always been a problem surrounding this scenario. I thought Microsoft fixed this particular problem :0/

Comment: Please mark as answered , as it might help some one who is stuck with this problem :)